# bcp doesn't show any errors, but doesn't copy any rows. I have xn xml format file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I'm using an xml format file that I generated via bcp, so I don't think that's it.  My .bcp file is 20 Gigs!  Here's the batch file I'm using:

```
bcp MyInputDB.dbo.mytable  format nul -S sourceserver\instance2 -c -x -f mytable.xml -t, -U user1 -P pw1
pause
title Start Time %time% Total number of rows is 275606414
bcp MyInputDB.dbo.mytable out "mytable2.bcp" -S sourceserver\instance2 -f mytable.xml -U user1 -P pw1 -c
echo Completed at  %time%
pause
title Start Time %time% Total Number of Rows is 275606414
bcp MyOutputDB.dbo.mytable in C:\mypath\mytable2.bcp -S MyHostName\MyInstance -f mytable.xml -U user2 -P pw2    
echo Completed at  %time%
```

I see:

```
Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 39500
```

A few rows of my .bcp file look like:

```
953     10      0       2019-01-12 19:09:41.480
953     20      0       2019-01-12 19:12:06.397
```

However, the mytable.xml format file looks like:

```
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="21"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
 </RECORD>
```

This doesn't seem to jibe.  It looks like it's expecting a .csv file.  Any way I can change my delimiter to tabs?

Comment: There are no commas in your file sample, try replacing them in format file with `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

When BCP processes the file without error and you get 0 rows, this typically means that BCP did not find the delimiter it was told to look for. It searched and searched thru the entire file and did not find the chain of delimiter you specified in the format file (or that it uses by default).

As Roger stated, the file appears to be tab delimited, but your format file is specifying the first column as having a comma delimiter.

So, BCP reads in byte after byte and never finds a comma before it reaches the end of the file... so, no data to load. BCP ran successfully and you have no rows loaded.